# Where does "docker images" look when outputting a list of images

Tags: docker, kubernetes

A word of warning, this is my first posting, and I am new to docker and Kubernetes with enough knowledge to get me into trouble.
I am confused about where docker container images are being stored and listing images.

To illustrate my confusion I start with the confirmation that "docker images" indicates no image for nginx is present.
Next I create a pod running nginx.

`kubectl run nginx --image=nginx` is succesful in pulling image "nginx" from github (or that's my assumption):

```
    Events:
      Type    Reason     Age   From               Message
      ----    ------     ----  ----               -------
      Normal  Scheduled  8s    default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/nginx to minikube
      Normal  Pulling    8s    kubelet            Pulling image "nginx"
      Normal  Pulled     7s    kubelet            Successfully pulled image "nginx" in 833.30993ms
      Normal  Created    7s    kubelet            Created container nginx
      Normal  Started    7s    kubelet            Started container nginx
```

Even though the above output indicates the image is pulled, issuing "docker images" does not include `nginx` the output.

If I understand correctly, when an image is pulled, it is being stored on my local disk. In my case (Linux) in `/var/lib/docker`.

So my first question is, why doesn't `docker images` list it in the output, or is the better question where does `docker images` look for images?

Next if I issue a `docker pull` for `nginx` it is pulled from what I assume to be Github. `docker images` now includes it in it's output.

Just for my clarification, nothing up to this point involves a private local registry, correct?

I purposefully create a basic local Docker Registry using the docker registry container thinking it would be clearer since that will allow me to explicitly specify a registry but this only results in another issue:

```shell
docker run -d \
    -p 5000:5000 \
    --restart=always \
    --name registry \
    -v /registry:/var/lib/registry \
    registry
```

I tag and push the `nginx` image to my newly created local registry:

```shell
docker tag nginx localhost:5000/nginx:latest
docker push localhost:5000/nginx:latest

The push refers to repository [localhost:5000/nginx]
2bed47a66c07: Pushed
82caad489ad7: Pushed
d3e1dca44e82: Pushed
c9fcd9c6ced8: Pushed
0664b7821b60: Pushed
9321ff862abb: Pushed
latest: digest: sha256:4424e31f2c366108433ecca7890ad527b243361577180dfd9a5bb36e828abf47 size: 1570
```

I now delete the original `nginx` image:

```
docker rmi nginx
Untagged: nginx:latest
Untagged: nginx@sha256:9522864dd661dcadfd9958f9e0de192a1fdda2c162a35668ab6ac42b465f0603
```

... and the newely tagged one:

```
docker rmi localhost:5000/nginx
Untagged: localhost:5000/nginx:latest
Untagged: localhost:5000/nginx@sha256:4424e31f2c366108433ecca7890ad527b243361577180dfd9a5bb36e828abf47
Deleted: sha256:f652ca386ed135a4cbe356333e08ef0816f81b2ac8d0619af01e2b256837ed3e
```

... but from where are they being deleted?
Now the image `nginx` should only be present in localhost:5000/? But `docker images` doesn't show it in it's output.

Moving on, I try to create the nginx pod once more using the image pushed to `localhost:5000/nginx:latest`.

```
kubectl run nginx --image=localhost:5000/nginx:latest --image-pull-policy=IfNotPresent
```

This is the new issue. The connection to localhost:5000 is refused.

```
    Events:
      Type    Reason     Age   From               Message
      ----    ------     ----  ----               ------- 
      Normal   Pulling    1s    kubelet            Pulling image "localhost:5000/nginx:latest"
      Warning  Failed     1s    kubelet            Failed to pull image "localhost:5000/nginx:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get "http://localhost:5000/v2/": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5000: connect: connection refused
      Warning  Failed     1s    kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
      Normal   BackOff    0s    kubelet            Back-off pulling image "localhost:5000/nginx:latest"
```

Why is it I can pull and push to localhost:5000, but pod creation fails with what appears to be an authorization issue? I try logging into the registry but no matter what I use for the username and user password, login is successful. This confuses me more.
I would try creating/specifying `imagePullSecret`, but based on docker login outcome, it doesn't make sense.

Clearly I not getting it.
Someone please have pity on me and show where I have lost my way.

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), your question is a little all over the place. `docker images` will look in `/var/lib/docker`. You're deploying to kubernetes, the images will be stored on whichever node the image is pulled on inside the cluster. The docker registry will store the images in it's data volume. Kubernetes won't resolve localhost to the IP of your host PC, it does not know where to pull the images from regardless of authentication.

Comment: Also, images are pulled from [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/), not [Github](https://github.com).

Comment: Also, kubernetes and docker are not the same thing! You should focus on learning Docker first, because Kubernetes is an orchestration tool that works on top of Docker. :)

Comment: Also, `localhost` inside a docker container points to the `container` itself - not the physical or virtual machine you are running Docker / Kubernetes on.

Comment: soon you will forget docker, and you will start using crictl. but no pb!

Answer (score 3):

I will try to bring some clarity to you despite the fact your question already contains about 1000 questions (and you'll probably have 1000 more after my answer :D)

Before you can begin to understand any of this, you need to learn a few basic things:

1. Docker produces images which are used by containers - it similar to Virtual Machine, but more lightweight (I'm oversimplifying, but the TL;DR is pretty much that).
2. Kubernetes is an orchestration tool - it is responsible for starting containers (by using already built images) and tracking their state (i.e. if this container has crashed it should be restarted, or if it's not started it should be started, etc)

Docker can run on any machine. To be able to start a `container` you need to build an image first. The image is essentially a lightweight mini OS (i.e. alpine, ubuntu, windows, etc) which is configured with only those dependencies you need to run your application. This image is then pushed to a public repository/registry (hub.docker.com) or to a private one. And afterwards it's used for starting containers.

Kubernetes builds on top of this and adds the "automation" layer which is responsible for scheduling and monitoring the containers. For example, you have a group of 10 servers all running `nginx`. One of those servers restarts - the `nginx` container will be automatically started by k8s.

A kubernetes cluster is the group of physical machines that are dedicated to the mentioned logical cluster. These machines have `labels` or `tags` which define the purpose of physical node and work as a constraint for where a container will be scheduled.

Now that I have explained the minimum basics in an oversimplified way I can move with answering your questions.

1. When you do `docker run nginx` - you are instructing docker to pull the `nginx` image from https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx and then start it on the machine you executed the command on (usually your local machine).
2. When you do `kubectl run nginx --image=nginx` - you are instructing Kubernetes to do something similar to `1.` but in a cluster. The container will be deployed to a `random` machine somewhere in the cluster unless you put a [nodeSelector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector) or configure [affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/). If you put a `nodeSelector` this container (called Pod in K8S) will be placed on that specific `node`.
3. You have started a `private registry` server on your local machine. It is crucial to know that `localhost` inside a `container` will point to the `container` itself.
4. It is worth mentioning that some of the `kubernetes` commands will create their own `container` for the execution phase of the command. (remember this!)
5. When you run `kubectl run nginx --image=nginx` everything works fine, because it is downloading the image from `https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx`.
6. When you run `kubectl run nginx --image=localhost:5000/nginx` you are telling kubernetes to instruct docker to look for the image at `localhost` which is ambiguous because you have multiple layers of `containers` running (check 4.). This means the command that will do `docker pull localhost:5000/nginx` also runs in a docker container -- so there is no service running at port `:5000` (the registry is running in a completely different isolated container!) :D
7. And this is why you are getting `Error: ErrImagePull` - it can't resolve `localhost` as it points to itslef.
8. As for the `docker rmi nginx` and `docker rmi localhost:5000/nginx` commands - by running them you removed your `local copy` of the `nginx` images.
9. If you run `docker run localhost:5000/nginx` on the machine where you started `docker run registry` you should get a running nginx container.

You should definitely read the [Docker Guide](https://docs.docker.com/get-docker/) **BEFORE** you try to dig into Kubernetes or nothing will ever make sense.

Your head will stop hurting after that I promise... :D

Comment: What you say regarding localhost makes sense, but does not match in practice. If it has any bearing on the matter, I am running a single node minikube cluster in a Photon OS VM 
created using VirtualBox. To put it another way, the host on which my minikube single node cluster and registry container are running is a Photon OS VirtualBox VM and following these instructions to deploy a registry server. Using localhost as used in the instructions is not behaving as anticipated. By the way your link to Docker Guide is being useful (not finished yet). Thanks

Comment: Sorry, instructions I refer to are found here: https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#run-a-local-registry.

Comment: `> but does not match in practice.` 

It actually does, but you haven't gotten to it yet so it probably doesn't make that much sense. You can run many containers on a single docker instance (or node). Each one of those container's `localhost` points to the container itself. So if you try to access `localhost:5000` from an `nginx` container you are ending up with accessing `nginx:5000` (localhost == nginx container in this case) :)

Comment: In addition to my comment above - keep in mind that `kubernetes` will execute the `kubectl` commands using a disposable container.  So when you execute `kubectl run ...` it will spin a few other containers which do `docker pull` on the nodes this is scheduled to run (it doesn't matter that you have just one node in your particular minikube setup). You should use a direct IP address instead to avoid this issue or setup a DNS record for an internal domain.

Comment: You mention to "use a direct IP address instead". The IP to use could be found in the output of docker inspect <registry container ID/name>? And should it be necessary to add that IP to /etc/docker/daemon.json as an insecure repository?

Comment: You could do what you said, or `docker run -dp 5000:5000 registry` which will create a reverse proxy exposing `hostPort:5000` on the machine where docker runs and will point that to `registryContainerPort:5000`. Then you could use your internal IP (i.e. `192.168.X.Y` or `10.X.Y.Z`). As for the docker daemon - I don't remember. In our company we use `podman` which gives a lot of flexibility regarding repository configuration. Last I checked docker this issue was active - https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/11815 so you are on your own with that part. :)

Comment: That is what I have done.
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry
docker inspect registry|grep IPAddress
     "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
curl -X GET http://172.17.0.2:5000/v2/_catalog
     {"repositories":["getting-started","harbor-db","nginx"]}
 docker exec -it registry ls /var/lib/registry/docker/registry/v2/repositories/
     getting-started  harbor-db  nginx
The expected content is there in the registry container at /var/lib/registry.
If I create a pod using 172.17.0.2:5000/getting-started:latest as the image repository I get connection refused.

Comment: I have it working now, or at least most of the way. Apparently minikube "uses its own local Docker registry that's not connected to the one on your local machine". I followed instructions from this link https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-run-locally-built-docker-images-in-kubernetes-b28fbc32cc1d. Next I should want to use different mount point location for the storage, but another day.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2):

## TL;DR

`docker images` lists images stored in the [docker daemon's data root](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/), by default `/var/lib/docker`.

---

You're deploying images to Kubernetes, the images are pulled onto the node on which the pod is scheduled. For example, using [Kubernetes in Docker](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/):

```shell
kind create cluster
kubectl run nginx --image=nginx
docker exec -it $(kubectl get pod nginx -o jsonpath={.spec.nodeName}) crictl images
```

[image: crictl images]

> [`crictl` is a command-line interface for CRI-compatible container runtimes.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/crictl/)

---

Docker images are pulled from [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/) by default, not [Github](https://github.com). When using a local `docker registry`, images are stored in the `registry`'s data volume. The `docker registry` [storage may be customized](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#storage-customization), by default data is stored in ([`storage.filesystem.rootdirectory`](https://docs.docker.com/registry/configuration/#storage)) `/var/lib/registry`.

You can use tools like [`skopeo`](https://github.com/containers/skopeo) to list images stored in a `docker registry`, for example:

```shell
skopeo list-tags docker://localhost:5000/nginx --tls-verify=false
```

[image: skopeo list-tags]

Comment: When I create the registry (docker run) and tag an image as localhost:5000/ and push, there is no /var/lib/registry. Doing "find / -name registry" as root does not find it. BTW, my host machine is a VirtualBox VM running Photon OS. Unfortunately, I have found skopeo package for it yet. Thanks, Mark

Comment: @RoyalCoachman `/var/lib/registry` inside of the `registry` container, not on your host, e.g. `docker exec -it registry ls -alF /var/lib/registry`.